# How to compile ejabberd hooks in Eclipse

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am trying to make simple `ejabberd` hooks or module. For this I follow these steps using `eclipse`.

1. create Erlang project and I gives `reference` to `ejabberd` source code ,             which is I have download from `github`.
2. Now I write code

   ```
   %% @author anuj
   %% @doc @todo Add description to hello_word.

   -module(hello_word).
   -behavior(gen_mod).
   -export([start/2,stop/1]).

   start(_Host, _Opt) ->
          ?INFO_MSG("Loading module 'mod_hello' ", []).

   stop(_Host) ->
             ok.
   ```

**Now i am compile it using this command**

```
(ErModule1_ejabberd@anuj)2> c(hello_word).
```

**This gives this error message to me**

```
hello_word.erl:11: undefined macro 'INFO_MSG/2'
hello_word.erl:8: function start/2 undefined
hello_word.erl:6: Warning: behaviour gen_mod undefined
error
```

Can anyone correct in this proccess how can i make a simple hook for ejabberd and compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INFO_MSG is a macro defined in `logger.hrl`. You need to include it in your file:

```
-include("logger.hrl").
```